# TD-DFT transition dipole moment vector does not align with experimental data

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, dipole, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I have been modelling excited states of some molecules with similar stucture using TD-DFT theory, however, I have encountered an issue that sometimes transition dipole moment does not align with the direction of experimental. For example, for molecule 1 the right direction of a transition dipole moment is with B3LYP functional and CAM-B3LYP functional results in a dipole moment in an opposite direction (the results were independent of the basis set). For molecule 2 the B3LYP functional yielded worse results than CAM-B3LYP. What could be the issue? I have done explicit geometry optimizations and frequency calculations (no imaginary frequencies were found) for each functional and basis set.

Comment: A possible error could be the identification of the excited state involved in the transition.  It can happen that excited states switch places if there are other excited states energetically close by. Another case are systems with charge-transfer states, which typically have very different energies in Cam-B3LYP and B3LYP.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, @HansWurst. However, it is known from the experiments for sure that it is really the S1 state that we are searching for. $S_0->S_1$  and $S_0->S_2$ transitions differ in about 100 nm, so, I believe, the switch of states is not the case here (as the involvement of the molecular orbitals also states that the states should be correct), however, I am not sure about the charge transfer involvement in the system. Any other types of the issues that could be the case?

Comment: I am not familiar with measurements of the transition dipole moments but there shoudn't be an "absolute" direction since it is an off diagonal element of an hermitian operator. The negative and positive direction should be equivalent since we can only determine the magnitude square of $|\vec \mu_{if} \cdot \vec E| = |-\vec \mu_{if} \cdot \vec E|$ but I am not an expert when it comes to this so i could be wrong. Perhaps someone else who is more familiar with this topic can provide more help.

Comment: @HansWurst, thank you very much for the insights!